# Django logging PermissionError with TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: django, logging

I am trying to make Django create and rotate new logs every 10 minutes using `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. My settings is as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/site.log',
            'backupCount': 10,
            'when':'m',
            'interval':10,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

The first log file is created successfully. But when it is time to rotate the log file, I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'F:\\logs\\site.log' -> 'F:\\logs\\site.log.2021-05-22_19-18'
```

How do I configure the logging so that the current log is copied to a timed log and new data written to the main log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. The solution that seems to work for me is including the flag **--noreload** when running the server.
This allows the logs to be rotated correctly although I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this file handler is not suitable for Windows, as any opened file cannot be moved or renamed. As it may work fine under some circumstances when using `./manage.py runserver`, it will fail when trying to use it wit any production-ready wsgi or asgi server as those servers are spawning multiple processes that are not aware of other ones having the log file open.

Comment: then what is the solution / correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Probably using `WatchedFileHandler` and implementing log rotation separately.